# Is number of quasi-kernels NP-hard?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, computational-complexity

A *quasi-kernel* in a directed graph D is an independent subset of vertices $S$ so that for every $v \in V(D)-S$ either $v->s$ for some $s \in S$ or $v->w->s$ for some $w \in V(D)-S, s \in S$.

**Equivalently**, a set $S$ is a quasi-kernel if $d(s,t) \geq 2$ for every $s,t \in S$ and $d(v,s) \leq 2$ for every $v \in V(D)-S,s \in s$.

Chvatal & Lovasz had proved that every digraph has a quasi-kernel (very easy proof by induction) and Jacob & Meyniel had proved that a graph without a kernel has at least three quasi-kernels.

My question is:

> Is counting the number of
>   quasi-kernels NP-hard?

Comment: The $s\in s$ quantify in the equivalent statement should be "for some $s\in S$ depending on $v$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reduction that works even if the directed graphs are required to be simple. I'll argue that there is a polynomial time algorithm which, given a graph $G$, outputs a directed graph $G'$ such that the number of independent sets in $G$ is the number of quasi-kernels in $G'$. Hence the number of quasi-kernels is NP-hard to calculate.

Take $G$, direct each edge arbitrarily, and for each vertex $v$ in $G$ add a directed path $v\rightarrow v'\rightarrow v''$ of length 2, directed away from the vertex. Call the resulting graph $G'$. (So $|V(G'|=3|V(G)|$ and $|E(G')|=|E(G)|+2|V(G|$.) Vertices of the form $v''$ must be in any quasi-kernel, and so vertices of the form $v'$ are not in any quasi-kernel, and the only condition on the original vertices are that two adjacent vertices cannot both be in a quasi-kernel. So the number of quasi-kernels in $G'$ is the number of independent sets in $G$.

This gives #P-completeness and NP-hardness of approximation (see M. Dyer, L.A. Goldberg, C. Greenhill and M. Jerrum, [On the relative complexity of approximate counting problems](http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~leslie/publications.html#relative), Algorithmica 38(3) 471-500 (2003)).

Comment: So when directly converted to SAT it is counting IS (via 2SAT) with additional clauses (maybe again 2SAT)?

Comment: I am not sure I get it: not every independent set of $G$ will give you a quasi-kernel of $G^{'}$. It seems you have to start with a quasi-kernel of $G$ to get a quasi-kernel of $G^{'}$ - or am I missing some argument here?

Comment: @Felix: I am claiming that every independent set $I$ of $G$ gives a quasi-kernel $I\cup\{v''\mid v\in V(G)\}$ of $G'$, and that every quasi-kernel of $G'$ is of this form.

Comment: @Colin: Suppose that $G$ is an oriented $4$-cycle and let $I=\{v\}$ for any $v \in V(G)$. Then $I$ is not a quasi-kernel of $G$ and $I \cup \{v^{''}$ is not a quasi-kernel of $G^{'}$.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: calling the vertices $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$, I am claiming that $\{v_1,v_1'',v_2'',v_3'',v_4''\}$ is a quasi-kernel of $G'$. Which condition fails?

Comment: @Colin: I got it now, thanks! You are right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the condition $ d(s,t) \geq 2 $ means there is no outgoing edge from $s$ to $t$
which is very close to independent set in undirected graphs.

Here is an argument why your problem is #P complete via reduction from independent set.

Given undirected graph $G$ make it directed by adding both $(s,t)$ and $(t,s)$.
The condition $ d(s,t) \geq 2 $ means $s$ and $t$ are not adjacent in $G$ and your set $S$
is an independent set for $G$.

Counting independent sets is #P complete.

Comment: But not every independent set gives a quasi-kernel!

Comment: Hm, indeed, I missed the additional condition... Thanks.